# Webview or iframe in django python

Tags: python, html, django, iframe

How to put an iframe, or something similar(like a webview), in my website such that the request for the iframe is sent from server side instead of client browser? I am using django in backend. I want to use iframes for viewing of regular sites like google.com.

Answer (score 1):

if your are trying to edit a html file and want to show iframe in it.... then you can do this

```
import webbrowser

f = open('helloworld.html','w')

message = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><iframe src="#"></iframe></body>
</html>"""

f.write(message)
f.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('helloworld.html')enter code here
```

Comment: I want to view an external website in iframe, say youtube and user should be able to interact with it as one normally does.

Comment: <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jza8FH8dQNs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: How will this ensure that the request is sent from server side? Please explain.